# potential ambiguity: in an hour

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"in + a length of time" is said to have two meanings: before the end of a particular period (i.e., within a period fo time), or at the end of that period. How do we know which applies? Consider, for example, the following:

> a. Can we get to the airport in an hour?
>
> b. He can get to the airport in an hour.
>
> c. He learned to swim in two months.

Which sense applies? And why?

Comment: "at the end of that period", as you differentiate it from the first definition, seems to be a description for a very specific instance of time, rather being about a period or duration. Would you provide an example for this very case? I understand your examples as if they are intended to imply a period of time.

Comment: "He learnt to drive in two months" is given by Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary as an example of the "at the end of a period of time" sense.

Comment: hmm, that might be opinion based, I  construe the "in an hour", as 59 minutes and 59 seconds regardless. So goes for in a week and in two months. It might be an OCD thing. :embarrassed emoji: Maybe the context or the tone of voice would make me think different. I don't know!

Comment: This question is wrong because 'in' doesn't mean 'before the end of a particular period' or 'within a period of time'. 'In' means 'at the end of' and 'within means before the end of'. "He learned to swim in two months." This sentence means he took the duration of two months to learn swimming. It means he was able to swim at the end of two months from a specific time in the past, NOT before the completion of two months.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question. You might want to read the passage from Longman English Grammar by L. G. Alexander: "In and, more formally, within, sometimes mean 'before the end of a stated period of time, which may be present, past or future:
/ always eat my breakfast in ten minutes
I finished the examination in (within) an hour and a half"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, both **a** and **b** could mean either that the journey could *end* in one hour from now, or that the journey will *take* one hour regardless of departure time.

> a. Can we get to the airport in an hour?
>
> b. He can get to the airport in an hour.

As in a lot of cases you will come across in English, context is everything. An example of duality of meaning I was taught in school was "*my father travels to work in a bowler hat*", which could mean he wears a hat while travelling, or that the hat is his vehicle. Obviously, the latter is ridiculous, so you wouldn't think that for a moment in a real situation. Likewise, if either of your two statements were said in a conversation, one would hope that the wider context would make it clear what was meant.

There is no ambiguity in **c**:

> He learned to swim in two months.

Because "learned" is in the *past tense*, this could only have happened in the past. It cannot mean *in two month's time*. For this sentence to have the same ambiguity as the previous two it would need to match the tense, ie "*he can learn to swim in two months*".

Comment: Could you give an example of a context where those sentences would be interpreted as the journey *beginning* in an hour? I can't seem to interpret them that way at all. Only as "the journey time is (under) an hour" or "the *arrival time* could be (less than) an hour from now" (which are essentially the same thing as each other, if you assume the journey can start immediately).

Comment: @ChrisH Hi Chris, perhaps this is particular to British English, but we idiomatically use expressions like "I can't get to the shops" to mean that we can't leave the house, or "get to work!" to mean "go to work". Basically, "get to" can mean to start your journey, rather than the end of it. If this isn't the case in American English I can add a disclaimer?

Comment: perhaps regional, but it'd be more specific than that (I'm also British). I'm familiar with "get to work", for example, as an instruction to go to work (*right now*). But (at least for me) once a time is added, like "get to work in an hour", that unambiguously means *being there* in an hour.

Comment: @Astralbee You are talking about a different kind of ambiguity. I'm asking about "before the end of a particular period (i.e., within a period fo time), and "at the end of that period. "

Comment: Longman English Grammar (by Louis Alexander) gives the following example, where "in" and "within" are said to have the same meaning: I finished the examination in/within an hour and a half.

Comment: @ChrisH I would say "I'm going to get to work in an hour" to mean I will *leave* for work in an hour. I suppose it could be a contraction of "get *off*", but nevertheless it is idiomatic.

Comment: @Apollyon you're right, there is a third possible meaning. Well, it seems that some people disagree with me about the third, so I've edited my answer to reflect the two that you highlighted. Either way, I'm correct about example 'c' because it happened in the past so it cannot be speaking about an end time in the future.

Comment: @Astralbee I don't doubt that that's idiomatic somewhere, I was just somewhat surprised/confused as I haven't encountered it before (and have encountered exactly the same phrasing, but with a different meaning). I'd only understand that as you telling me when you were going to arrive at work.

Comment: @ChrisH immaterial now as i've edited it out. Apollyon is correct that there are at least 2 possible meanings even if you don't agree with mine!

Comment: @ChrisH I'm also really surprised you haven't encountered this in British English. If someone said "I can't get to the shops", would you assume they'd begun their journey but been unable to complete it?

Comment: @Astralbee no. If they'd started the trip but couldn't complete it I'd expect "I *couldn't* get to the shops". "I can't get to the shops" tells me they know they won't make it to the shops, but doesn't say anything about why (it could be because they have other obligations taking up all their time, or it could be because the buses aren't running, or anything else) But I don't follow the connection - as I said, it's only when you put a specific time with "get to" that we're disagreeing on the meaning.

Comment: I would say, " to learn" is a process, it involves ups and downs. So, to me that would mean the learning process was a period of two months. I mean regardless of the time reference, past or future, **in a certain length of time** conveys a period or duration of time.